# polymer core-ajax - get http status code from response

Tags: polymer

I'm playing with core-ajax element and I need to extract http status code from ajax response. I was looking for it in this.$.ajax.* but cannot find it anywhere. I believe it must be exposed somewhere, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Huh, it looks like it's not currently exposed as a field. I can see where having easy access to the status for the current request would be valuable, patches welcome!

You could listen for either the `core-response`, `core-error` or `core-complete` event depending on your use case. Each of them receives an event with an xhr field, which has the status at xhr.stats.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I need to distinguish success family responses, like OK, NO_CONTENT, ACCEPTED. It don't feel right to return error instead of accepted. Even if I do with error I can still handle one additional successful case. Regarding xhr.stats, when I handle core-response event this.$.ajax.xhr.stats is undefined.

Comment: If you're looking for the http status code, don't look on $.ajax, look on the event object that's passed to your error handling function. I'm not sure what you mean by "It don't feel right to return error instead of accepted."

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstand you.. Anyway, there is no stats field on event object, but I found status here: event.currentTarget.activeRequest.status Thanks!